# Google Proximity Beacon API : Build a web app to detect beacons (Progressive App)

Tags: javascript, beacon, estimote, eddystone, proximityapi

I'm trying to build a web app to detect beacons in my room.

So far I have integrated the Google Beacon API on a webpage and using Google Client JS API have used the below services:

1. `https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beacons` to fetach all the beacons of my project
2. `https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beaconinfo:getforobserved?key=+ apiKey` to get all the attachments of my active beacon.

All the above is working fine, but this is different from what I'm looking for. Is there a way that when the web page open in chrome, a function is triggered whenever it finds a beacon. As per my undertanding this is possible using a native app (Android or iOS).

Google Nearby Notifications was an option to advertise URL but [Nearby Notifications is Temporarily Muted](https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/overview)

A little confused with the purpose of Google Beacon API.

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately, no, there are no browser-based APIs that let you change what is on a web page in a browser based on beacon detection.**

For this to work, there would need to be JavaScript bindings to bluetooth scan events, something which does not exist on any platform.  Google has some Chrome OS extensions that let you interact with Bluetooth via JavaScript, but these are not available in the Chrome browser on Android or in Windows/Mac versions.

Comment: Thanks @davidgyoung. I guess then native is the way to go.